# AppCenter Fails to Fetch Updates

Tags: appcenter, ppa, repositories

Running Elementary OS Hera, Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Linux 5.3.0-46 generic, GTK 3.22.30.

Long story short: evaluated syncEvolution 1.5.3 - it didn't work for what I needed.

Uninstalled it, as well as removed the key as I was getting an error related to the key; I now get the following message when opening the AppCenter in Elementary OS to run software updates:

Failed to Fetch Updates

This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

W: GPG error: http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 728C11EAB3526360
E: The repository 'http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 728C11EAB3526360)

If I add in the key:

:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 728C11EAB3526360
[sudo] password for mainadmin: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.yWVXSbLaIt/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 728C11EAB3526360
gpg: key A36DBD1343D03AD9: public key "SyncEvolution " imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

I will then get the following from AppCenter:

Failed to Fetch Updates

This may have been caused by external, manually added software repositories or a corrupted sources file.

invalid: EXPKEYSIG 728C11EAB3526360 SyncEvolution 
E: The repository 'http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable InRelease' is not signed.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: http://downloads.syncevolution.org/apt stable InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 728C11EAB3526360 SyncEvolution )

If I remove the key, I'm back to the beginning.

I am also unable to run updates using apt-get.

Assistance is appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the relevant lines out of /etc/apt/sources.list; issue resolved.

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered?